# jsdom get text without image

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I am trying to use jsdom to get a description from an article.
The html code of the article is

```
<p><img src="http://localhost/bibi_cms/cms/app/images/upload_photo/1506653694941.png" 
style="width: 599.783px; height: 1066px;"></p>
<p>testestestestestestestest<br></p>
```

Here are my nodejs code for getting the description from the content, It seems  it will get the text from first p tag and print out empty string. So I just want to get the content in **p** tag that contains no image. Anyone help me on this issue?

```
const dom = new JSDOM(results[i].content.toString());
if (dom.window.document.querySelector("p") !== null)
results[i].description = dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you could test against Node.TEXT_NODE but that is erroring for me on nodejs for some reason so (using gulp just for testing purposes):

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const fs = require('fs');

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const html = yourHTML.html';

gulp.task('default', ['getText']);

gulp.task('getText', function () {

  var dirty;
  dirty = fs.readFileSync(html, 'utf8');

  const dom = new JSDOM(dirty);
  const pList = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("p");

  pList.forEach(function (el, index, list) {

    console.log("p.firstElementChild.nodeName : " + el.firstElementChild.nodeName);

    if (el.firstElementChild.nodeName !== "IMG") {
      console.log(el.textContent);
    }
 });

 return;
})
```

So the key is the test

```
el.firstElementChild.nodeName !== "IMG"
```

if you know that either an img tag or text follows the p tag.  In your case the firstElementChild.nodeName you want is actually a br tag but I assume that isn't always necessarily there at the end of the text.

You could also test against an empty string ala :

```
  if (el.textContent.trim() !== "") {}  // you may want to trim() that for spaces
```